# React Native - Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

So, im getting started with react native and redux. I'm trying to setup a basic app state, just a `counter` property to increment when a button is pressed.
Basically, no error is thrown but the state doesnt get updated, at least in the screen the `counter` keeps having the same value.

Ill try to document the code bellow.

App.js - its where I create the store and a basic reducer

```
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'

import App from './src/App'

const initialState = { counter: 0 }
const reducer = (state=initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type)
  {
     case 'INCREASE_COUNTER':
       return {counter: state.counter++}
  }
  return state;
}
const store = createStore(reducer)

class AppProvider extends React.Component {
  render() {
     return (
        <Provider store={store}>
           <App />
        </Provider>
     )
  }
}

export default AppProvider
```

./src/App.js - its where i have the View implemented

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class App extends React.Component  {
   render() {
      return (
         <View>
           <Button title="increase" onPress={this.props.increaseCounter}/>
           <Text>Counter: {this.props.counter}</Text>
         </View>
      )
   }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {counter: state.counter};
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    increaseCounter: () => dispatch({type: 'INCREASE_COUNTER'}),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

So no error is thrown but the screen still shows `Counter: 0` as I press the button.
I'm probably missing something here.

Any help would be awesome.
Thanks and happy programming!

Comment: try using case 'INCREASE_COUNTER':
       return { ...state, counter: state.counter++};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should pass `mapDispatchToProps` to `connect` function.

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect